# How to define a custom stateful Op holding values of variables in Tensorflow C++?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I was trying to define a new Op with state and then wrap it with python. And the problem is I want this op holding variables between Session.run() (Like initializing a int *foo* in this Op and then add the *foo* by 1 each time run. What expected is *foo* is 1 more than last run.)

I have tried REGISTER_OP().SetIsStateful() but it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to implement this kind of op?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I find how to do this.

According to the implement of tensorflow variables.The stateful values can be stored in resource manager defined [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e073322452e41e76754314aa75d543d071003fc5/tensorflow/core/framework/resource_mgr.h#L55).

Briefly, define a struct which contains the state you want to store. And implement the virtual methods in Class ResourceBase. Then restore this stateful struct by Lookup function which retrieves the values from containers managed by Resource Manager.

The point is you need to retrieve the ResourceManager from the context like this rather to define a new one:

```
ResourceMgr *rm = context->resource_manager();
```